# Creating a dynamic Prolog list of arguments with the C++ interface

Tags: c++, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

Im trying to create a dynamic list of arguments in a C++ program and call a rule in Prolog using the C++ interface to SWI-Prolog. It's something like this:

```
    //includes

    int main
    {

      // other declarations

      PlTerm   myVariable;
      PlTermv  myVector(3), vectorArgs(2);
      PlTail   myList(myVector[0]);


      //Here I want to receive texts from keyboard or otherwise in char* variables 
      //and store it in "myVector",but I don't know how to do it correctly. 
      //I think it will not work anyway.

      vectorArgs[0]= myVariable;
      vectorArgs[1]= myList;

      //myRule receives a variable and a list with three interchangeable elements.
      PlCall ("myRule",vectorArgs); 

      //the true program is not so simple XD
      cout<<"\nMy Variable: "<<(char *)myVariable<<'\n'; 

      return 0;
    }
```

The result has to be "myVariable" as the first position of "vectorArgs" and "myList" as the second containing a list as "[text1, text2, text3]". I got success using PlCompound to compose the list, but it will not serve as the resulting list is constant, and I need a dynamic list. I mean, the list will change in a loop until the program reaches the end, then at a certain moment can become something like "[text3, text1, text2]".
At certain times it seems that only the first element is present in the list, this is causing malfunction of the program and my rule is failing. I consulted the documentation but it shows a lot more C++ code embedded in Prolog than not, and that's what I'm trying to do, I'm doing queries to the Prolog knowledge base using the list, and performing actions in the C++ program, based on the response contained in "myVariable". Thanks a lot!